# How to do Grouping Total by names wise in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have Table like this

```
DECLARE @T Table 
(
  EmployeDesc VARCHAR(20),
  Empname Varchar(50),
  headOffice INT,
  SubOffice INT
);
```

Sample Data

```
INSERT INTO @T(EmployeDesc, Empname, headOffice, SubOffice) VALUES 
('Sale','Rob',2,3),
('Discount','Rob',6,10),
('Sale','BOB',2,3),
('Discount','BOB',2,3);
```

How can we achieve this in SQL server

```
EmployeDesc Empname headOffice  SubOffice

Sale        Rob         2          3
Discount    Rob         6         10
  **Rob Total**         8         13
Sale        BOB         2          3
Discount    BOB         2          3
  **BOB Total**         4          6
```

we can do in using `UNION ALL` or Running Totals but is there any other way to do this .

Can anyone suggest me

Comment: What is wrong with using `UNION ALL`?

Comment: which version of SQL you use?

Comment: I have loads of Data .lots of union all's will be there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Grouping with ROLLUP:**

```
;with X AS
(
    SELECT
        EmployeDesc, 
        Empname,
        SUM(headOffice) AS headOffice,
        SUM(SubOffice) AS SubOffice
    FROM @T
    GROUP BY Empname,EmployeDesc WITH ROLLUP
)
SELECT  
    CASE ISNULL(EmployeDesc,'') WHEN '' THEN '**'+Empname+ ' Total**' ELSE EmployeDesc END AS EmployeDesc, 
    CASE ISNULL(EmployeDesc,'') WHEN '' THEN '' ELSE Empname END AS Empname,    
    headOffice,
    SubOffice
FROM X
WHERE X.Empname IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `grouping sets`:

```
select EmployeDesc, Empname,
       sum(headOffice) as headOffice, sum(SubOffice) as SubOffice
from @T
group by grouping sets ( (EmployeDesc, Empname), (EmpName) );
```

Comment: How to remove NULL and make that as one row

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Group],
       [Name],
       SUM([SalesYTD]) AS 'Total Sales'
FROM #TempTable
GROUP BY [Group],
         [Name]
WITH ROLLUP
```

Result Set:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Group                Name                 Total Sales ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Europe               France                74569.00   ║
║ Europe               Germany               59456.00   ║
║ Europe               United Kingdom        78327.00   ║
║ Europe               NULL                 212352.00   ║
║ North America        Northwest            208774.00   ║
║ North America        Southeast            145477.00   ║
║ North America        Southwest            164232.00   ║
║ North America        NULL                 518483.00   ║
║ Pacific              Australia             93403.00   ║
║ Pacific              NULL                  93403.00   ║
║ NULL                 NULL                 824238.00   ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```